# Why does http://169.254.269.264/ in an AWS instance have so many versions apart from latest?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, metadata

Inside an AWS instance, I go to the browser and hit http://169.254.169.254. If am getting some many files and folder kind of thing including dates like of thing and the latest one is also there in that. I want to know is there any specific meaning of that?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From [Instance Metadata and User Data - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html):

> The earlier versions are available to you in case you have scripts that rely on the structure and information present in a previous version.